# time response of this system

Tags: linear-systems

I'm  doing a little exercise, that requests to calculate the time response of the next system
[image]

so

I proceed the next way
$r=2x$
$e=u-2x$
$m=k(u-2x)$

then
$x=\frac{1}{s+1}[k(u-2x)]$
making all the math
$\frac{x}{u}=\frac{\frac{k}{s+1}}{\frac{s+3}{s+1}}=\frac{k}{s+3}$
$k=1$
 so
$\frac{x}{u}=\frac{1}{s+3}$

I understand that the time response is the inverse Laplace transform of this fraction
$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{1}{s+3})=e^{-3t}$
But the teacher told me that was incorrect and refused to explain why, I don't understand if the numeric value is wrong or the notation used.

Comment: By *time response*, do you mean the *impulse response* of the system? If yes, your answer is correct for $t>0$. 
(It should be $e^{-3t}u(t)$)

Comment: Why the $u(t)$?